# How to get the next biggest int value in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can someone help me with a SQL query for this situation.

I have a table with a surrogate key and a business key. For example this table:

```
ID ------ contact_id 

1 -------- 100 
2 -------- 100 
3 -------- 200
4 -------- 100 
5 -------- 100
```

Does anyone know a query to get the next biggest ID of a contact_id. I tried something with joins but I don't know the next biggest id part.

edit: i don't mean for a specific contact_id, more in general that could be used for all.

As suggested I should've put the expected outcome in the post. The problem is already solved by Anonxen by now but for future reference/other people with similar questions: 
With "next biggest value" I mean the next int in ID per contact_id. I don't mean the highest of all id numbers of a contact_id, but only the next id that is linked to that contact. So that in the example it would skip the id's that are not related to the contact_id but it should be the following number. 
I am at id 1 and expect the query to look for the next id, so that would be 2. But if I would be at id 2 I want to go to id 4.

Comment: So for `ID` 1 what you expect as next biggest value?

Comment: What does "next biggest ID of a contact_id" *mean*? Make sure to include expected output (and more robust input). Also, show what queries are being tried and explain how they [don't quite] work.

Comment: @user2864740 This is not to oppose your comment, I just want to know since I'm new to SO: what do you mean with a more robust input? Did you expect more data or columns, examples? Because in my case I believe it's actually all the data that is relevant for this question (the rest are columns such as name, birth day etc). I will take your feedback into account.

Comment: @Kim A third (different) contact ID, for example - but more importantly here, the *desired* output. (Thanks for editing that in, it'll make the question more useful to others in the future.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it if I understand you properly :)

```
---Supply the ID and the Contact_ID
DECLARE @ID INT = 1
    ,@C_ID INT = 100;


WITH OrdCte AS(

SELECT ID,Contact_ID,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Contact_ID ORDER BY ID) ord 
FROM #sample

) 
    SELECT B.ID,B.Contact_ID 
    FROM OrdCte A 
    JOIN OrdCte B 
    ON A.Contact_ID = B.Contact_ID
    WHERE A.Contact_ID = @C_ID AND A.ID = @ID AND A.ord+1 = B.ord;
```

Comment: This was what I was looking for! Only that the local variables shouldn't always be the same but I changed around a bit and it's working great. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

use top N to select one result and add condition for the certain contact_id Ex:1 then order by ID to get the next biggest ID:

```
select top(1) ID from table_name where ID> 1 order by ID
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @ContactId INT
SET @ContactId = 100

;WITH ContactsCTE AS
(
    SELECT ID,
           Contact_ID,
           ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY ID) AS rn
    FROM   Contacts
    WHERE  Contact_Id > @ContactId
)
SELECT ID,
       Contact_ID
FROM   ContactsCTE 
WHERE  rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need the highest ID for a specified contact_id, try this:

```
select max(ID)
from <your_contacts_table>
where contact_id = <your_value>
```

for example:

```
select max(ID)
from contacts
where contact_id = 100
```

Comment: Sorry I described it maybe too vague at first, I meant for the column contact_id in general.

Comment: The highest ID in your table? If so, you simply remove the WHERE clause from my query.

Comment: No, I mean that I would like to get the highest ID of a contact_id but it doesn't need to be 100 or any other int, I want to use it in a standard way so it could be used for all contact_id's.

Comment: Do you mean the highest ID for every contact_id? If so, you have to do something like: select contact_id, max(id) from contacts group by contact_id

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you expect the **next big** value for `contact_id` 200, so in this case it will use the same `contact_id` as **next big**

```
Select Main.*,ISNULL(NextB.contact_id,Main.contact_id) as NextBig 
From TableName Main
     Outer APPLY (Select contact_id 
                  From TableName T 
                  Where T.Id>Main.Id and T.contact_id >Main.contact_id) As NextB
```